# Stacked Google visualization chart

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

Is it possible to make the bars in [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/XWERy/1/) graph stacked like in [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/44ze6/1/) chart?

Please let me know if this is possible and how to do this.
I've got to stick with Google Visualization Charts.

You can also throw the following codes in [HERE](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart):

Stacked graph:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addRows([
    ['2004', 1000, '1M$ sales in 2004', 400,  '$0.4M expenses in 2004'],
    ['2005', 1170, '1.17M$ sales in 2005', 460, '$0.46M expenses in 2005'],
    ['2006', 660,  '.66$ sales in 2006', 1120, '$1.12M expenses in 2006'],
    ['2007', 1030, '1.03M$ sales in 2007', 540, '$0.54M expenses in 2007']
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data,
       {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        isStacked: true,
        width:600, height:400,
        vAxis: {title: "Year"},
        hAxis: {title: "Sales"}}
      );
}
```

Other graph:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
    ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
    ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
    ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
    ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
    ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
    ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
      );
}
```

Comment: I found out that this isn't supported by google visualization API at the moment. There is a workaround which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/7yHz7/) but it is to much work and not usefull for me. And it is by the way a some kind of hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Google visualisation is a requirement for your project I'm not sure how to do this, but [dimple](http://dimplejs.org) makes this kind of thing very easy, see the examples [here](http://dimplejs.org/examples_index.html).

Comment: You were right. The links do work properly right now. And yes i'm restricted to google visualization chart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to make the bars as u required. In your options you need to add this statement
   `isStacked:true`
Here is the working [sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/32aRh/) For more google chart related queries take a look at [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/)

Comment: That's not like I mentioned. Like in the first example the data has been underdivided. I don't want to change the look but I want the bars in the first example to be stacked in the way they are shown right now.